Clean architecture: inverting dependency of EF DbContext
I stumbled upon this article that explains the principles of clean architecture. I want to apply those principles in ASP.NET Core + EF. I got stuck at this part:

The Application layer only depends on abstractions, defined in
interfaces, and these interfaces are implemented in outer layers. For
example, persistence concerns (such as saving an item to a database)
are defined only in terms of requirements; the persistence logic in
the Infrastructure layer implements these requirements.

Sounds perfectly reasonable, the Application layer should not know that EF is a thing, and only expose an interface which will then be implemented by the DB context in the Infrastructure layer.
However, when I try it, I encounter a blocker. Say my DB Context looks like this:
public class DbContext {
   public DbSet<Person> Persons {get; set;} = null!;
}

According to Clean Architecture, the DbContext should now implement IDbContext that resides in the application layer:
public interface IDbContext {
   public DbSet<Person> Persons {get; set;}
}

However, DbSet is a type defined in EF, so the application layer would need to depend on EF too, which, as per my understanding of the article and Clean Architecture, is against the principles.
The article also links a repository, and when I look at the dependencies of the Application layer, I find out that they actually made the Application layer depend on EF too.
Any ideas how to get out of this and achieve an Application layer independent of the infrastructure layer and EF?

You can define an interface that exposes IQueryable

I thought about that, but IQueryable<Person> does not have Add on it (unlike a DbSet), and when checking, the Add method is not coming from any interfaces, but is implemented on the DbSet directly, so I unfortunately still do not see how to make this work.

If you absolutely need to abstract yourself away from Entity Framework, then maybe you could look into Repository Pattern: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

@TheHvidsten I do not "absolutely need to", I am learning, so I am wondering if the shiny looking theory might work in practice, which the article itself contradicts a bit by linking the repository which showcases what the article does not say :-D. Thank you for the link, will read up on it a bit

@TheHvidsten that's not what this link says at all. What you proposed is an ugly antipattern. A DbContext is a high-level multi-entity Unit-of-Work, not a database connection. Putting a low-level CRUD class over it completely breaks its functionality both as an ORM and as a disconnected UoW

@PanagiotisKanavos I agree that it is an antipattern, but not wanting to use Entity Framework properly doesn't give many good choices, so if you absolutely must then there are many bad choices (hence the "absolutely need to").

There are different approaches (with different potential downsides):

Use IQueryable interfaces instead of DbSet - though it will still be a leaky abstraction (for example methods like Include are EF-specific, so you will need to reference it when those will be needed)

Do not expose context as part of your domain/application level at all V1:
Use repositories (and/or Unit of Work) on top of EF Core. Note that this approach (or some versions of it) can be considered as an antipattern (for example)

Do not expose context as part of your domain/application level at all V2:
Use the CQRS pattern (or something similar) when on the domain/application level queries and commands will be declared as interfaces and will be implemented on the infrastructure level via EF.



I'm fully against putting CRUD classes over DbContext, not at all against proper multi-entity Domain repositories. With ORMs like EF those end up being thin wrappers and containers for queries though. On the other hand, the single-entity CRUD classes people call "generic repositories" typically start by breaking concurrency, then implement Insert methods that cause deletions, and then people come here asking why their code doesn't work

Thank you for the overview! In case the clean architecture around EF is not really achievable in practice, how is this problem practically solved? Just ignore the clean architecture and couple the application layer to EF aka the persistence provider?

@karlosss TBH in my apps (unless the are "simple" ones) I tend to use EF Core as "DAL" level tool used inside repository or CQRS abstractions which pairs with clean architecture quite nicely. Of course there are cases when abstraction becomes leaky (for example when you need to implement some complex logic in transactional context) but usually it was not that frequent in my projects. Also note that there is always a "hidden" 4th option - patterns are general guidelines, not laws, they can be  broken.

@GuruStron by any chance, do you have a public repository of one of these apps which would showcase the usage where i could "get inspired"? I think seeing a real, working code would help me with understanding a lot. Before I break the pattern, I want to be sure I have valid reasons for that, because from my experience, breaking patterns usually does not end up going well :)

"Clean Architecture" is a book title, not a pattern. It evolved into a common marketing term for related ideas and books. A common description of patterns is A solution to a problem in a context. What works for a specific problem in one situation (context) isn't necessarily the best solution in another situation. Typically, it will be obvious when you'll need separate models for EF, the application layer and ... your REST resource model and API DTOs. What makes a good database model isn't always a good API DTO. An Abstractions layer used for both will break as the application grows

For example, the Blazor Hosted project template creates a Shared project where you put entities used by both the server and Blazor WASM (GUI) client. That's very helpful until .... you need to add annotations to add validation to the GUI, which in turn affect EF. Or realize that what's Required in one form is not Required in another. That's how ViewModels were created, to serve the needs of different views instead of building the entire GUI on top of a single Application model. If you use OData or GraphQL the annotations will affect the API as well.

@karlosss "by any chance, do you have a public repository" - sorry but no, I have nothing publicly available in this area, there are some publicly available made by others but a lot of them have the same problem - they show very succinct happy path which a bit obfuscates the corner cases (but on the other hand gives you the general idea). Also you can look into the ABP framework templates which have similar approach AFAIK.

will take a look, thank you!
